# Do I need to add `onKeyDown` to `button` for accessibility compliance? (WCAG 2.0)

Tags: reactjs, button, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I have a button than when clicked will expand a card with more information

Do I need to add `onKeyDown` to `button` for accessibility compliance?

Or is that redundant because the element is already a `button`?

I am missing something else to comply with `WCAG 2.0`?

Here is my collapsible button code with `react`

```tsx
const ariaPressed = checked ? "true" : "false";

return (
  <button
    tabIndex={0}
    role="button"
    component="button"
    aria-pressed={ariaPressed}
    aria-expanded={ariaPressed}
    onClick={toggleChecked}
  >
    {checked ? "Hide Versions" : "View Versions"}
  </button>
);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need `onKeyDown` since you're using a native `<button>`.  A button will drive the `onClick()` whether you click with a mouse, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> with the keyboard, or tap on a mobile device.

As a side note, you also don't need `tabindex=0` since `<button>`s are natively keyboard focusable.

And you don't need `role=button` since that's the default role for a native `<button>`.

I would also get rid of `aria-pressed` since you're using `aria-expanded`.  As long as you toggle the value of `aria-expanded` between "true" and "false", that's all you need.